# Select and update specific rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a DF:

```
DF:
Inp | M |  N | P 
 GF | 1 | 12 |
 GF | 1 | 12 |
 GF | 1 | 13 |
```

and I want to place a value in any rows where `Inp` = `GF` and `M` = 1 and `N` = 12 to get an output like this:

```
DF2:
Inp | M |  N | P 
 GF | 1 | 12 | X
 GF | 1 | 12 | X
 GF | 1 | 13 |
```

I know I can select by multiple attributes using `.loc` like this:

```
df.loc[(DF['Inp'] = 'GF') & (DF['M'] = 1) & (DF['N'] = 12)]
```

But I'm not sure how to then place a value in column P. Maybe I'm not on the right track.

Comment: See piR's solution in the duplicate, specifically point **3. boolean arrays** which is exactly this kind of selection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are on the right track. Just add the column and asign your value:

```
df.loc[(DF['Inp'] = 'GF') & (DF['M'] = 1) & (DF['N'] = 12), "P"] = X
```